# 404 Not Found, what is wrong on Route and Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I was tried to find the problem, but still not found what is wrong on my code.
Can anybody help what is wrong on my code.

route (web.php)

`Route::get('/pegawai','PegawaiController@index');`

PegawaiController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class PegawaiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //mengambil data dari table pegawai
        $pegawai = DB::table('pegawai')->get();
 
        // mengirim data pegawai ke view index
        return view('index',['pegawai' =>$pegawai]);

    }
}
```

My database is using mysql and for another program is can run just for this is 404 not Found.
I'm using laravel 8.6

And I tried to create new project and is no problem, but on existing project is always `404 Not Found`

Any idea why this happen??

Comment: which version of laravel you are using.

Comment: @PHPGeek I'm using laravel 8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved this case,
just code on command prompt `php artisan route:cache` and then my code is work

Answer (score 1):

change route to  :
`Route::get('/pegawai', [PegawaiController::class, 'index']);`

and check `htaccess` file exist in public folder

run `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

You should contain the namespace in `Route::get` facade function second parameter.

AS-IS

```
Route::get('/pegawai','PegawaiController@index');
```

TO-BE

```
Route::get('/pegawai','App\Http\Controllers\PegawaiController@index');
```

or

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PegawaiController;
Route::get('/pegawai', PegawaiController::class);
```

Comment: `Route::get('/pegawai','App\Http\Controllers\PegawaiController@index');` use this not working

Comment: what is the url you are hitting?

Comment: @Jayant `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pegawai`

Comment: Have you try to change the route in `web.php` e.g `Route::get('/', 'controller@index');` or have to test the route if it is running or not `Route::get('/pegawai', function() { return 'this is a pegawai page'; });`.

Comment: hi @Jayant I tried `Route::get('/pegawai', function() { return 'this is a pegawai page'; });` and still not found.  Why this happen?

Comment: hi @Jayant, I was tried but still `404 Not Found` and when I create new project on Laravel is can work, why this happen?

Comment: just `php artisan route:cache` on command prompt and it works

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the latest version of laravel, then you should use the path of laravel in route like ---

```
Route::get('/pegawai',[\App\Http\Controllers\PegawaiController,'index']);
```

if show some error please remove \ in the controller path.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I was trying it not show error only 404 not found, I'm was develop other application and use same route there is no problem. but only for this is have trouble.

Comment: I was try create new project it can be work, but on existing project it always `404 Not Found` any idea , what happen?